# Making table view section expand swift

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift3, swift2

I am following [this](http://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/) tutorial for expanding and collapsing my table view section. As this demo is done in swift 2.2 I have made all the changes according to swift 3.0 . I am stuck at the below function at if condition(currentSectionCells[row]["isVisible"]) which gives me error as "Type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any' has no subscript members)'".

```
func getIndicesOfVisibleRows() {
    visibleRowsPerSection.removeAll()

    for currentSectionCells in cellDescriptors {
        var visibleRows = [Int]()

        for row in 0...((currentSectionCells as! [[String: AnyObject]]).count - 1) {
            if currentSectionCells[row]["isVisible"] as! Bool == true {
                visibleRows.append(row)
            }
        }

        visibleRowsPerSection.append(visibleRows)
    }
}
```

I have tried type casting it as below

```
    func getIndicesOfVisibleRows() {
    visibleRowsPerSection.removeAll()

    for currentSectionCells in cellDescriptors {
        var visibleRows = [Int]()

        for row in 0...((((currentSectionCells) as? NSMutableArray)?.count)! - 1) {

            let temp = [currentSectionCells][row] as? NSMutableDictionary
            let temp2 = temp?["isVisible"] as! Bool

            if temp2  == true {
                visibleRows.append(row)
            }
        }

        visibleRowsPerSection.append(visibleRows)
    }
}
```

But this gives me a crash at runtime on this line "let temp2 = temp?["isVisible"] as! Bool"
Crash says "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION" and the temp shows as nil.

Please help guys. TIA

Table View Delegate and Data Source

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if cellDescriptors != nil {
        return cellDescriptors.count
    }
    else {
        return 0
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return visibleRowsPerSection[section].count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let currentCellDescriptor = getCellDescriptorForIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "sectionCellIdentifier" {
        if let primaryTitle = currentCellDescriptor["secondaryTitle"]
        {
            cell.sectionTitleLabel.text = primaryTitle as? String
        }
    }
    else if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "shortAnswerCell" {
        cell.questionTitle.text = currentCellDescriptor["primaryTitle"] as? String
        cell.questionTextView.text = currentCellDescriptor["secondaryTitle"] as? String
        cell.answerTextView.text =  currentCellDescriptor["answerTitle"] as? String

    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let indexOfTappedRow = visibleRowsPerSection[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    let temp = cellDescriptors[indexPath.section] as? NSArray
            let temp2 = temp?[indexOfTappedRow ] as? NSDictionary
            let temp3 = temp2?["isExpandable"] as! Bool

    if temp3 == true {
        var shouldExpandAndShowSubRows = false
        if temp3 == false {
            // In this case the cell should expand.
            shouldExpandAndShowSubRows = true
        }

        temp2?.setValue(shouldExpandAndShowSubRows, forKey: "isExpanded")

        for i in (indexOfTappedRow + 1)...(indexOfTappedRow + (temp2?["additionalRows"] as! Int)) {
            (temp![i] as AnyObject).setValue(shouldExpandAndShowSubRows, forKey: "isVisible")
        }
    }
    getIndicesOfVisibleRows()
    tblExpandable.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: indexPath.section) as IndexSet, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I worked on that tutorial as well and completed it successfully in swift3.Your solution is given below modify accordingly.

```
    class yourClass: UIViewController
{


      @IBOutlet weak var profileTableView: UITableView!
    internal var visibleRowsPerSection = [[Int]]()
    internal var cellDescriptors: NSMutableArray!
        // VIEW DID LOAD
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        profileTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        loadProfileControllerData()
        profileTableSetUp()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func loadProfileControllerData(){
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "CellDescriptor", ofType: "plist") {
            cellDescriptors = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: path)
        }
        getIndicesOfVisibleRows()
        profileTableView.reloadData()
    }
    // SHOW PARENT VISIBLE ROWS AND SAVE THERE ROW INDEX IN ARRAY
    func getIndicesOfVisibleRows() {
        visibleRowsPerSection.removeAll()
        for currentSectionCells in cellDescriptors.objectEnumerator().allObjects as! [[[String:Any]]]{
            var visibleRows = [Int]()
            for row in 0..<currentSectionCells.count {
                if currentSectionCells[row]["isVisible"] as! Bool == true {
                    visibleRows.append(row)
                }
            }
            visibleRowsPerSection.append(visibleRows)
            print(visibleRowsPerSection)
        }

    }
    // GET REQUIRED OBJECT OF TYPE [String: Any]
    func getCellDescriptorForIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [String: Any] {
        let indexOfVisibleRow = visibleRowsPerSection[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        let cellDescriptorss = cellDescriptors[indexPath.section] as! NSArray
        let data = cellDescriptorss.object(at: indexOfVisibleRow) as! [String:Any]
        return data
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}

//----------------------


// EXTENSION TO OUR PROFILE CLASS THAT DETERMINE OUR CLASS CONFIRM 2 IMPORTANT DELEGATES
extension profileViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
    //MARK-: TABLE VIEW DELEGATE FUNCTIONS

    // RETURN NUMBER OF  SECTION IN TABLE VIEW
    public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
        if cellDescriptors.count != 0{
            return cellDescriptors.count
        }
        else{
            return 0
        }

    }

    // RETURN NUMBER OF ROWS IN EACH SECTION OF TABLE VIEWS
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return visibleRowsPerSection[section].count
    }

    /* Return object of UITableViewCell that contains table SECTON data and USER profile data */

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let currentCellDescriptor = getCellDescriptorForIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
        let menuCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String, for: indexPath) as! yourCellClass

        if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "parent"{

        }
        else if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "child"{
            menuCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        }

               return menuCell
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

        let indexOfTappedRow = visibleRowsPerSection[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        let cellDescriptorss = cellDescriptors[indexPath.section] as! NSArray
        var data = cellDescriptorss.object(at: indexOfTappedRow) as! [String:Any]

        if data["isExpandable"] as! Bool == true{
            var shouldExpandAndShowSubRows = false
            if data["isExpanded"] as! Bool == true{
                shouldExpandAndShowSubRows = false
                (cellDescriptorss[indexOfTappedRow] as AnyObject).setValue(shouldExpandAndShowSubRows, forKey: "isExpanded")
            }


            for i in (indexOfTappedRow + 1)...(indexOfTappedRow + (data["additionalRows"] as! Int)) {
                (cellDescriptorss[i] as AnyObject).setValue(shouldExpandAndShowSubRows, forKey: "isVisible")

            }
        }
        getIndicesOfVisibleRows()

        self.profileTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: indexPath.section) as IndexSet, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tushar that worked :). I have one more query. I am not getting proper sections. Only the first one is shown and it doesn't even expands.

Comment: @iDeveloper section part seems oak it should be visible.

Comment: No buddy, its not working yet. It crashed in the for loop. Don't know why its not working, also its not returning proper sections, I have 2 sections whereas it shows only one.

Comment: @iDeveloper The problem is in Swift 3 signature of method `numberOfSections(in:)` is changed check this answer of my http://stackoverflow.com/a/42664434/6433023 to get your correct section count

Comment: @iDeveloper provided you complete required details check and make sure everything okk.

Comment: @NiravD  I missed that.:P

Comment: @NiravD Thank You :) That was an eye opener. That worked. Up voted your answer as well.

Comment: @TusharSharma Buddy the sections work now, but problem still goes with expanding the sections. :( Still figuring out the issue. if I found it will surely post it here.

Comment: @iDeveloper you might be doing a point mistake somewhere it works like a charm for me.

Comment: I cross checked each and every line. Everything seems to be perfect. Still the sections won't work for me. :'( @TusharSharma

Comment: Hi @TusharSharma , just wanted to let you know that the sections are working as per requirement. What changes I did was just changed the didSelect method to swift 3.0 syntax. :) Thank You.Anyways I am posting the code as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for helping me out, I was stuck at a point where the sections weren't expanding even after your help, so just made some changes in the syntax as Swift 3.0 is very specific about type casting hence the didSelectRowAt wasn't functioning properly. Here is the complete didSelectRowAt method. Happy coding.

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

    let indexOfTappedRow = visibleRowsPerSection[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    if (cellDescriptors[indexPath.section] as! [[String: AnyObject]])[indexOfTappedRow] ["isExpandable"] as! Bool == true {
        var shouldExpandAndShowSubRows = false
        if (cellDescriptors[indexPath.section] as! [[String: AnyObject]])[indexOfTappedRow]["isExpanded"] as! Bool == false {
            // In this case the cell should expand.
            shouldExpandAndShowSubRows = true
        }

        ((cellDescriptors[indexPath.section] as! NSMutableArray)[indexOfTappedRow] as AnyObject).setValue(shouldExpandAndShowSubRows, forKey: "isExpanded")

        for i in (indexOfTappedRow + 1)...(indexOfTappedRow + ((cellDescriptors[indexPath.section]  as! [[String: AnyObject]])[indexOfTappedRow]["additionalRows"] as! Int)) {
            ((cellDescriptors[indexPath.section]  as! NSMutableArray)[i] as AnyObject).setValue(shouldExpandAndShowSubRows, forKey: "isVisible")
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3/4 without use of NSMutable arrays based on the tutorial and all the code wrapped in a model.

```
class CellsDescriptorModel {
private var cellDescriptors: [[[String:Any]]]!
private var visibleRowsPerSection : [[Int]]

var CellDescriptors : [[[String:Any]]] { get { return cellDescriptors }}
var VisibleRowsPerSection : [[Int]] { get { return visibleRowsPerSection }}

init(plist:String) {
    visibleRowsPerSection = [[Int]]()

    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:plist, withExtension: "plist") {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf:url)
            cellDescriptors = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil) as! [[[String:Any]]]
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    getIndicesOfVisibleRows()
}

func getCellDescriptorForIndexPath(indexPath: IndexPath) -> [String: Any] {
    let indexOfVisibleRow = visibleRowsPerSection[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    return cellDescriptors[indexPath.section][indexOfVisibleRow]
}

func expandCell(indexPath:IndexPath) {
    let indexOfTappedRow = visibleRowsPerSection[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    if cellDescriptors[indexPath.section][indexOfTappedRow] ["isExpandable"] as! Bool == true {
        var shouldExpandAndShowSubRows = false
        if cellDescriptors[indexPath.section][indexOfTappedRow]["isExpanded"] as! Bool == false {
            shouldExpandAndShowSubRows = true
        }

        cellDescriptors[indexPath.section][indexOfTappedRow]["isExpanded"] = shouldExpandAndShowSubRows

        for i in (indexOfTappedRow + 1)...(indexOfTappedRow + (cellDescriptors[indexPath.section][indexOfTappedRow]["additionalRows"] as! Int)) {
            cellDescriptors[indexPath.section][i]["isVisible"] = shouldExpandAndShowSubRows
        }
    }
    else {
           if cellDescriptors[indexPath.section][indexOfTappedRow]["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "DataPickerTableViewCell" {
            var indexOfParentCell: Int!

            for index in (0..<indexOfTappedRow).reversed() {
                if cellDescriptors[indexPath.section][index]["isExpandable"] as! Bool == true {
                    indexOfParentCell = index
                    break
                }
            }

            cellDescriptors[indexPath.section][indexOfParentCell]["secondaryTitle"] = ""
            cellDescriptors[indexPath.section][indexOfParentCell]["isExpanded"] = false

            for i in (indexOfParentCell + 1)...(indexOfParentCell + (cellDescriptors[indexPath.section][indexOfParentCell]["additionalRows"] as! Int)) {
                cellDescriptors[indexPath.section][i]["isVisible"] = false
            }
        }
    }

    getIndicesOfVisibleRows()
}

private func getIndicesOfVisibleRows() {
    visibleRowsPerSection.removeAll()
    for currentSectionCells in cellDescriptors {
        var visibleRows = [Int]()
        for row in 0..<currentSectionCells.count {
            if currentSectionCells[row]["isVisible"] as! Bool == true {
                visibleRows.append(row)
            }
        }
        visibleRowsPerSection.append(visibleRows)
    }
}
```

}